UPX anti unpacking (upx -d)
To start, I know that there is a post on this platform from 2013 that asked the same question but since it's been a while, I will ask it again.
A few months back I recall to find a github repo / software that makes it possible to randomize the startpoint of the UPX packed file. Now I'm curious which techniques there are to make upx -d not usable anymore. Not just changing the ELF header by one byte since that's an obvious one to solve.
